# Max possible probability of exponential distribution for given $\lambda$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

> The maximum possible probability an exponential distribution with an
> arbitrary parameter can give to the interval $[3,6]$ is :
>
> $(a) \ \ \dfrac{1}{2}$
>
> $(b) \ \ \dfrac{1}{3}$
>
> $(c) \ \ \dfrac{1}{4}$
>
> $(d) \ \ \dfrac{2}{3}$

My input:
$X \sim exp(\lambda)$

$f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x} ; x\ge0$

$F(6)-F(3)=e^{-3 \lambda}-e^{-6 \lambda}$

I started by putting different values of lambda and calculating probability. Which is very time consuming for the exam I am preparing for.

If I take $\lambda=\dfrac{1}{3}$ I get $0.232$

But there must be some other way to figure this out which I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You're trying to maximize the quantity
$$h(\lambda):=e^{-3\lambda}-e^{-6\lambda}$$
over all $\lambda>0$. This can be solved with calculus: take the derivative, set to zero, check you have a maximum.

Comment: $-3e^{-3\lambda}+6e^{-6\lambda}=0 \implies e^{-3\lambda+6\lambda}=2 \implies e^{3\lambda}=2 \implies \lambda=\dfrac{\log2}{3}$

,substituting in fucntion:
$e^{-3\frac{\log2}{3}}-e^{-6\frac{\log2}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

correct?

Comment: Wait, $e^{-6\frac{\log 2}3}$ is not $\frac 22$, it's $\frac14$.